# Grasshopper returned '"identifier expected" and "method must have a return type"

Tags: c#, grasshopper

I'm rather new at C#, or at least, when I dabbled in it, it's been a while. Around Line 88, I keep getting the error stated in the title. I'm really not sure, and I don't understand coding much, just the logic of things.
It worked for the second part, I'm not sure why my return is giving me errors. When I looked up the other solutions on this site, it mainly gave that it was an issue of capitalizations and the like, and I've tried playing around with that to no avail...

```
using Rhino;
using Rhino.Geometry;
using Rhino.DocObjects;
using Rhino.Collections;

using GH_IO;
using GH_IO.Serialization;
using Grasshopper;
using Grasshopper.Kernel;
using Grasshopper.Kernel.Data;
using Grasshopper.Kernel.Types;

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



/// <summary>
/// This class will be instantiated on demand by the Script component.
/// </summary>
public class Script_Instance : GH_ScriptInstance
{
#region Utility functions
  /// <summary>Print a String to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component.</summary>
  /// <param name="text">String to print.</param>
  private void Print(string text) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
  /// <summary>Print a formatted String to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component.</summary>
  /// <param name="format">String format.</param>
  /// <param name="args">Formatting parameters.</param>
  private void Print(string format, params object[] args) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
  /// <summary>Print useful information about an object instance to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component. </summary>
  /// <param name="obj">Object instance to parse.</param>
  private void Reflect(object obj) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
  /// <summary>Print the signatures of all the overloads of a specific method to the [Out] Parameter of the Script component. </summary>
  /// <param name="obj">Object instance to parse.</param>
  private void Reflect(object obj, string method_name) { /* Implementation hidden. */ }
#endregion

#region Members
  /// <summary>Gets the current Rhino document.</summary>
  private readonly RhinoDoc RhinoDocument;
  /// <summary>Gets the Grasshopper document that owns this script.</summary>
  private readonly GH_Document GrasshopperDocument;
  /// <summary>Gets the Grasshopper script component that owns this script.</summary>
  private readonly IGH_Component Component;
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the current iteration count. The first call to RunScript() is associated with Iteration==0.
  /// Any subsequent call within the same solution will increment the Iteration count.
  /// </summary>
  private readonly int Iteration;
#endregion

  /// <summary>
  /// This procedure contains the user code. Input parameters are provided as regular arguments,
  /// Output parameters as ref arguments. You don't have to assign output parameters,
  /// they will have a default value.
  /// </summary>
  private void RunScript(double div, double rad, bool boolt, ref object Geometry)
  {
    var geometry = new List<object>();
    var pattlines = new List<Line>();
    var tri = Tri(rad, boolt);
    Line[] tr = tri.GetSegments(); // array creation, data structure functions similar to dict
    pattlines.Add(tr[0]);
    pattlines.Add(tr[1]);
    pattlines.Add(tr[2]);

    var gm = new List<Polyline>();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < div){
      gm.AddRange(pattlines);
      pattlines.AddRange(Patterning(gm));
      i++;
    }
    Geometry = pattlines;
  }

  Patterning(List<Line>)
  {
    var patternLines = new List<Line>();
    foreach(Line l in pattlines){
      double le = l.Length;
      Point3d pS = l.PointAt(0.0);
      Point3d p0 = l.PointAt(1 / 3);
      Point3d p1 = l.PointAt(2 / 3);
      Point3d pE = l.PointAt(1.0);

      var rotate = new Line(p0, p1);
      rotate.Transform(Rhino.Geometry.Transform.Rotation(Math.PI / 3, p0));
      Point3d tip = rotate.PointAt(1.0);
      var line0 = new Line(tip, p1);
      var line1 = new Line(pS, p0);
      var line2 = new Line(p1, pE);

      patternLines.Add(line0);
      patternLines.Add(line1);
      patternLines.Add(line2);

    }
    return patternLines;
  }

  Polyline Tri(double rad, bool boolt)
  {
    var a0 = 0;
    var a1 = a0 + Math.PI * 2 / 3;
    var a2 = a1 + Math.PI * 2 / 3;
    var p0 = new Point3d(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0), 0);
    var p1 = new Point3d(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1), 0);
    var p2 = new Point3d(Math.Cos(a2), Math.Sin(a2), 0);

    var tripl = new Polyline();
    tripl.Add(p0);
    tripl.Add(p1);
    tripl.Add(p2);
    tripl.Add(p0);

    if (boolt == true){
      tripl.Reverse();
    }

    return tripl;


  }

  // <Custom additional code> 

  // </Custom additional code> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Method as

```
Patterning(List<Line>)
```

To

```
private List<Line> Patterning(List<Line>)
```

Your method is returning patternLines which is of type  **`List<Line>`**

Comment: Ah ok, it still gives me the error of requiring an identifier though, why is that?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: For line 88, where the error was, it just says Error(CS1001): Identifier expected.

The line 88 was the Patterning(List<Line>) line which I changed, but that only got rid of the method must have return type error :(

Comment: nope, but i can copypaste the new section of the code into the comments.

Comment: identitier expected means you are misisng , or ) brackets somewhere in code, open in visual studio and it will suggest you a fix

Comment: ah, I don't have visual studio though, I'm an architecture student, not a programmer, but we have to do parametric designing.